# Http Post Angularjs causing internal server error via Web API

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, http-post

I am having a simple http post insert operation from angularjs via web API. But I dont know why I keep getting internal server error. http GET functions are working fine. But for the http post, the data is inserting successfully into database via WebAPI but response from service is not being received. Getting internal server error 500.

WebAPI

```
 // POST: api/Website/InsertEmployee
[ResponseType(typeof(Employee))]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult InsertEmployee(Employee employee)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    objCSADBEntities.Employee.Add(employee);
    objCSADBEntities.SaveChanges();

    return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = employee.EmployeeID }, employee);
}
```

Angularjs Service

```
(function () {

    var app = angular.module('myApp');

    app.factory('websiteService', ['$http', function ($http) {
        var factory = [];

        factory.insertEmployee = function (webAPIHostName,employee) {
            var request = $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: webAPIHostName + '/Website/InsertEmployee',
                data: employee
            })
            return request;
        }

        return factory;
    }
   ]);
})();
```

Angularjs Controller(Where service is called there I am getting internal server error 500)

```
var employee = {
    EmployeeID: 1,
    Name: 'Test',
    Phone: '111-111-1111'
};

var insertEmployee = websiteService.insertEmployee($scope.webAPIHostName , employee);
insertEmployee.then(function (response) {
    alert("Submitted Employee Successfully.");
    //success response here
}, function (error) {
    // error handling here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify using fiddler or postman that your API call is returning what you expect? Once you can verify the WebAPI is returning the valid HttpStatus (200 to < 400), then you can check your front-end code (angularjs). Call webAPIHostName + '/Website/InsertEmployee' and add the JSON body (assuming its JSON) to your fiddler call. Change the Method to POST, and include in your header

Content-Type: application/json

If your response is not what you expect, try changing your API return from

```
return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = employee.EmployeeID }, employee);
```

to

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, employee);
```

If you can verify that your POST is working as expected, then check your angularjs.

As for Angularjs, your http call can be updated to

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('websiteService', ['$http', function ($http) {            
    var insertEmployee;

    insertEmployee = function (webAPIHostName, employee) {            
        return $http.post(webAPIHostName + '/Website/InsertEmployee', JSON.stringify(employee));
    }

    return {
        insertEmployee: insertEmployee
    };
}]);



// Angular Controller

var employee = {
    EmployeeID: 1,
    Name: 'Test',
    Phone: '111-111-1111'
};

websiteService.insertEmployee($scope.webAPIHostName , employee)
    .then(function (response) {
        alert("Submitted Employee Successfully.");
        //success response here
      }, function (error) {
        // error handling here
    });
```

Comment: This is working in my local but when i deploy to server i get this...do i need to do any iis server config

Comment: Could it be something to be configured on server to run webapi post

Comment: Have you used either Postman or Fiddler to verify you are getting a 200 returned from your live server? Can you post the exact response error you get from the 500 error?

Comment: With the `$http` service there is no need to stringify JavaScript object data. The AngularJS framework does it automacally.